# Буква Й при делении на слоги

Tags: слоги

На сайте [slogi.su](https://slogi.su/pravila.html) в разделе *Традиционная школа* приведены такие правила разбиения слов на слоги:

> В традиционной школе всё просто. Сколько гласных, столько и слогов, а как ребёнок разделит, не важно (лишь бы красиво звучало и ребёнку было понятно). Как бы школьника не научили делить на слоги, это нигде не отразится: ни на ОГЭ, ни на ЕГЭ (там таких заданий нет). Перечислим три простых правила школьной программы.
>
> - Слог образует гласный звук:
>   сте-на, ба-ран (с-тена, бара-н — неправильно).
> - Слог начинается с согласного, который стоит перед гласной:
>   мо-ло-ко, ко-ра (мол-око, кор-а — неправильно).
> - Буквы ь, ъ (которые не означают звуков), й нельзя отрывать от предыдущего слога:
>   лай-ка, конь-ки, подъ-езд (ла-йка, кон-ьки, под-ъезд — неправильно).
>
> В традиционной школе допускается вариативность: со-лнце или сол-нце, ко-мпью-тер или ком-пью-тер.

Меня смущает тут описание действий с буквой `Й`. Указанное правило требует её всегда относить к предыдущему слогу, и с `лай-кой` всё хорошо, но что если после `Й` идёт гласная, например `майор` и `фойе`? Ведь `Й` вместе с гласной образует отдельный звук, причём гласный, так что мне кажется очень странным разделять слоги между ними (`май-ор`, `фой-е`).

Кстати, если там же заглянуть в следующий раздел *Школа углублённого изучения,* то можно прочитать

> - Согласные буквы, образующие один звук, нельзя разносить в разные слоги. Один звук образуют сочетания зж [ж:], тся, ться [ц:].
>   у-е-зжать, но-си-тся, де-ла-ться (в традиционной школе верно также: у-ез-жать, но-сит-ся, де-лать-ся).

В целом, правила из этого раздела кажутся совместимыми с традиционными (с учётом вариативности), но именно в словах с Й перед гласной наблюдается противоречие - углублённый вариант оказывается некорректным для традиционных правил.

Это действительно верное различие между ними, или просто вариант с гласной потерялся в традиционных правилах?

PS: [Вопрос на ruSO с реализацией этого алгоритма.](//ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1155314/178988)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> > > но что если после Й идёт гласная, например майор и фойе?

Все очень просто. На сайте - грубая ошибка. Можно, конечно, как сейчас говорят, "найти отмазку", приняв за факт, что речь-де идет о предыдущем слоге, а Й перед гласной к нему заведомо не относится, но тогда практический смысл самого "правила" исчезает, превращаясь в бесполезную мантру "когда все известно, то так и надо". То есть, надо думать, что не это имели в виду изобретатели рассматриваемого правила. К сожалению, подобные ляпы на сайтах разных самоделкиных - не новость. Могу только в который уж раз дать рекомендацию не связываться с неавторитетными источниками, как бы красиво они не выглядели.

На самом деле существуют несколько точек зрения на природу слога, принцип слогоделения, соответственно, - разный, в некоторых случаях рекомендации представителей разных школ не совпадают. Но это всё академический уровень, наш же случай прост и очевиден. И в академических, и в школьных методиках Й перед гласной обозначает согласный звук *йот*, который очевидным образом принадлежит "следующему" слогу.

Еще одно некорректное утверждение - в отношении букв Ъ и Ь, которые никаких звуков сами по себе не обозначают. Но слоги-то состоят из звуков. Так каким образом предлагается относить к ним ноль звука? Кстати, в отношении буквы Й в отдельных случаях можно спросить нечто подобное. По одной из научных школ - и это попало даже в некоторые школьные учебники - буква Й в словах типа "папайя", "алилуйя", Гийю "имя собственное", тейю (род ящериц) - и по некоторым теориям даже "бойи" (племя) - обозначает ноль звука, поскольку "йот" порождается последующей гласной буквой.
Все это совершенно не отражено в правиле.

И последнее замечание. В школе слогоделение изучают главным образом в связи с правилами переноса. Это несколько оправдывает авторов материалов, подобных представленному. Если речь идет только о переносе, без претензий на объяснение самой природы слога (а, судя по всему, ваши материалы как раз такого сорта) ляпы источника не столь заметны, и представление о "немой" букве, входящей в "слог", можно до какой-то степени оправдать, но тогда возникает другое недоразумение. Слогоделение для целей орфографии (переноса) и реальное, звуковое, слогоделение не совпадают. Раньше учили, да и до сих пор иногда учат, что перенос осуществляется "по слогам" (за очень немногими исключениями). Сейчас, особенно после появления лет тридцать назад  продвинутых методов компьютерной верстки, от такого подхода лучше отказаться.

Все современные (нежесткие) правила переноса исчерпывающе формулируются в шести пунктах.
(по памяти даю).

~1. Нельзя переносить или оставлять неперенесенной одну букву и сочетания Й+гласная в абсолютном начале и конце слова (слова типа *фойе, Гойя, иогурт* не переносятся).
~2. Нельзя разрывать переносом сочетание С(огласная)+Г(ласная), буквы Ъ, Ь и Й оговариваются особо.
~3. Ь и Ъ всегда остаются на непереносимой части строки, перенос по границе сочетаний ЙА, ЙИ, ЙУ, ЙЕ, ЙО  возможен тогда и только тогда, когда перед Й идет гласная (перенос слов  типа *гайярдия* или *зухдийят* по границе ЙЯ не нормирован).
~4. Нельзя отрывать приставку от корня, если он начинается с гласной (вытекает из 1), но нельзя в этих случаях и отрывать одну букву от приставки: перенос типа *ра-зыскивать* запрещен (хотя последнее часто не выдерживается).
~5. В составных словах типа "пароход" следует придерживаться структуры слова перенос *па-роход* не рекомендуется (этот пункт часто не выдерживается).
~6. Перенос составных слов с дефисом рекомендуется выполнять по дефису (раньше, наоборот, исключалось), повторения дефиса на новой строке по современным правилам не требуется. Нельзя переносить по дефису части слова, не являющиеся корнем (*по-русски, как-то, кое-кто*).
Дополнительно:
~7. Имена собственные, особенно плохо знакомые читающему, переносить не рекомендуется.

Кажется, все. За исключением, возможно, каких-то совсем уж редких случаев. Если вы реально хотите иметь алгоритм, пригодный к реализации и более или менее адекватный правилам, то настоятельно советую использовать эти шесть или семь пунктов вместо всех заморочек со слогоделением, которые ко всему прочему не учитывают некоторых особенностей правил (начиная с четвертого).

Надеюсь, что ответил если не строго по букве вопроса, то по сути.

(+)

> Согласные буквы, образующие один звук, нельзя разносить в разные
> слоги. Один звук образуют сочетания

Полагаю, это правило надуманное. Ко всему прочему его очень трудно корректно организовать: Бо*тс*вана - здесь один звук или два? А "ра*зж*ечь"?

(++) Ой, забыл сразу написать.

> Согласные буквы, образующие один звук, нельзя разносить в разные
> слоги. Один звук образуют сочетания зж [ж:], тся, ться [ц:].

Сочетания *"тся", "ться"* образуют ***один звук***?! Убивать надо за такое. И это в материале, претендующем на право считаться методикой?!

Comment: _"Если вы реально хотите иметь алгоритм, пригодный к реализации и более или менее адекватный правилам, то настоятельно советую использовать эти шесть или семь пунктов вместо всех заморочек со слогоделением"_ - алгоритм из этих правил не получится, они требуют выполнения морфемного анализа.

Comment: Про тся видимо имелось в виду `ть?с(?=я$)`, но сформулировано криво.

Comment: _"ЙА, ЙИ, ЙУ, ЙЕ, ЙО"_ - почему тут варианты с `И` и `Е`, а не с `Ы` и `Э`? В слове `фойе` явно йе сочетание не образуют. Вот тут _"буква Й в словах типа "папайя", "алилуйя", Гийю "имя собственное", тейю (род ящериц) - и по некоторым теориям даже "бойи" (племя) - обозначает ноль звука, поскольку "йот" порождается последующей гласной буквой."_ `И` оказывается в ряду с `Я`, а не `А`.

Comment: *почему тут варианты с И и Е, а не с Ы и Э* Найдите хоть одно слово в русском с ЙЫ или с ЙЭ. Вы вообще буквы от звуков отличаете?

Comment: *В слове фойе явно йе сочетание не образуют.* - что такое "сочетание" на вашем языке? Для меня в контексте разговора очетание - две рядом стоящие буквы в одном слове.

Comment: *Про тся видимо имелось в виду ть?с(?=я$), но сформулировано криво* - я понимаю, что криво сформулировано. Поэтому и предлагаю вам не ориентироваться на подобные источники. Особенно когда вы рассуждаете об алгоритмах.

Comment: *алгоритм из этих правил не получится, они требуют выполнения морфемного анализа* - а вы как хотели? Алгоритм, кстати, я подобный писал еще лет тридцать назад - с небольшими поправками на тогдашнюю ситуацию. Вполне рабочий. Во всяком случае куда более рабочий, чем весь этот набор кривых правил с левого сайта.

Comment: Буквы от звуков я отличаю, но как писать транскрипции давно забыл. По поводу слов с ЙЫ и ЙЭ я не знаю, но раз буквы существуют, то рано или поздно запросто откопается какое-0нибудь название, в котором после транслитерации буквы внезапно оказались в таком порядке :) Перед ЯЁЮИЕ оказывается мягкий звук, перед АОУЫЭ - твёрдый. Если перед одной из твёрдых поставить Й, то она начинает звучать так же, как соответствующая из мягких (т. е. два звука j и буква). Кажется логичным так и разделить.

Comment: Под сочетанием я имел в виду объединение в единый звук. Если бы это было так в слове `фойе`, то оно бы звучало просто как `фае`, но реально в нём Й произносится. Сорри, не помню точно, как транскрипцию записать, но надеюсь, смысл понятен.

Comment: *Под сочетанием я имел в виду объединение в единый звук.* - Понятно. Начитались кривых формулировок. Разберитесь в азах. ЙО, ЙЕ ИУ и прочее - никогда в один звук не сливаются. ***Никогда***, Карл.

Comment: *то рано или поздно запросто откопается какое-0нибудь название* - Не всегда. Есть сочетания просто запрещенные в русском. Ъ после гласной например. Транслитерация не поможет. И еще, я писал, что для имен собственных (именно них иногда актуальна транслитерация, а не транскрипция) - для имен собственных, не освоенных пока языком, правила переноса обычно не действуют. Их переносить вообще не рекомедуется.

Comment: *И еще насчет одного звука* То, что вы там "имели в виду" никого интересовать не должно. Компьюеру такое не объяснишь. Вы же программист - что напишете, то и будет выполнятся.

Comment: За сим, простите, все. Это, имхо, тупик. Да и движок уже давно ругается, а местные модеры не любят этой ситуации.

Comment: Вот город [Йыхви](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%99%D1%8B%D1%85%D0%B2%D0%B8). Так что всё рано или поздно найдётся. И я ж общаюсь, а не программу пишу, так что важно именно то, что понятно. Да, знаю, что Е и подобные обозначают 2 звука, тем не менее, по-другому я свою мысль объяснить не мог.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110896/discussion-between-qwertiy-and-behemothus).