# Перенос слова "меж-дуэтажными"

Tags: перенос

Правильно ли оформлен перенос слова "меж-дуэтажными"? Вроде как сложные слова делятся на стыке двух частей, и тогда правильно "между-этажными". Или возможны варианты?

Comment: Возможен такой вариант: межэтажные.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Вроде как сложные слова делятся на стыке двух частей, и тогда
> правильно "между-этажными".

По строгим классическим правилам - да. ***Между-этаж-ны-ми.***
Однако де-факто современные правила не такие жесткие, на что есть ряд причин, компьютерная верстка - в первую очередь.  Поэтому появление варианта "меж-дуэтажными", как бы дико он ни смотрелся, исключить нельзя.

Несколько слов добавлю.
"Междуэтажный" (и подобные) не считается сложным словом, "между"  здесь приставка.
В отношении же приставок в докомпьютерную эру действовало правило, что их нельзя разрывать при переносе, равно как нельзя отрывать от корня одну букву.
Но в целом правила переноса за всю историю их существования (примерно с середины XVIII века) постоянно менялись и последние полтора-два столетия сильно упрощались. Например, вариант "междуэтажны-ми" тоже был бы запрещен (разрыв флексии), в советскую эпоху это правило уже не действовало, хотя такой перенос не считался удачным.

Сейчас все программы используют систему правил переноса, не рассматривающую морфологию слова вовсе или использующую её крайне ограниченно.

Подробнее о современном состоянии системы правил переноса я писал здесь
[Буква Й при делении на слоги](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/461493)